# Regex to replace multiple characters with one and some condition

Tags: javascript, regex

Input string is like:

```
This is new update -(!@#$%)    1.0...
```

I have a string (title) I need to transform in order to use it as a link in the future.

Necessary:

1. Remove all special characters.
2. Replace multiple spaces with a single one.
3. Replace spaces with underlines.
4. Leave only points that are between numbers.

I'm not sure I'm doing everything right. Right now I am using the `.replace()` method a lot:

```
.replace(/[^a-z0-9_.\s]/gi, ' ')
.replace(/[\s\s+]/g, '_')
.replace(/[\.]/g, '.')
.replace(/[\s\s+]/g, '_')
```

What approach should I take to achieve the result?

Goal:

```
this_is_new_update_1.0
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure I'm doing everything right"_ - me neither, cause you failed to show anything of what you tried.

Comment: 1 needs a _proper_ definition of what you consider "special characters". 2 + 3 should be handled in one go.

Comment: Post what you have done so far. Don't expect people to cook lunch for you.

Comment: @CBroe I have added the methods that I used, but I feel that the approach itself is wrong. Perhaps you should write a full-fledged function or use some library to solve this problem?

Comment: @123 can you provide some more input string to suggest some regex. Just by looking at one input string it's not possible to think about the regex that gets the work done for you

Comment: To me, your approach makes a lot of sense (as you're using js) - take it step by step.  It may be possible to combine steps, but only do so if it doesn't confuse/complicate the code.   What's *not* working with the approach (ie ask about specific issue, rather than the general approach).

Comment: *Replace spaces with underlines* - if you already have underlines, you'll end up with multiple underlines, eg `_ example _` will be `__example__` - swap 2/3 if you don't want this (and make it "replace multiple underlines with a single one")

Comment: *Leave only points that are between numbers* - probably should come before 2/3.  Depends on if you are "removing points that are not between numbers" or replacing them with spaces/underlines.  Your "remove specials" doesn't "remove" it "replaces specials with spaces", so hard to tell if that's the desired action for "remove points".

Comment: For *points that are between numbers* (or more specifically *not between numbers* as they're the ones you want to remove) - you can use negative lookahead / negative lookbehind:  `.replace(/(?<!\d)[.](?!\d)/g, '')`  More info: https://regex101.com/r/I2nJDR/1

Comment: Why have 2 separate steps for replacing multiple spaces with a single space, then replacing the spaces with underscore? Just replace multiple spaces with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine *1* and *4*.

```
/[^a-z0-9._\s]|\.(?!\d)/gi
```

And, *2* and *3*.

```
/ +/g
```

```js
var s = 'This is new update -(!@#$%)    1.0...'
s = s.replaceAll(/[^a-z0-9._\s]|\.(?!\d)/gi, '')
s = s.replaceAll(/ +/g, '_')
s = s.toLowerCase()
console.log(s)
```

Comment: I think this does not handle `Replace multiple spaces with a single one.` Test it with the string `This   is new update -(!@#$%)    1.0...`

Answer (score 0):

With two regex replace:

1. `/(\d\.\d)|\.|[^\s\w]/g`
2. `/\s+/g`

First replace #1 with first capture group, followed by #2 with `_`.

#1 matches one of the following

1. `(\d\.\d)` - a digit followed by a decimal point and yet another digit. If this it matched it's captured.
2. `\.` - a period/full stop
3. `[^\s\w]` - a character that isn't a space (`\s`) or a word character (`\w`)

This is replaced with capture group #1 ($1) which is empty if any part but the first matched. If the first is matched, it's the *digit-period-digit* combination captured (i.e. not changing anything).

After that all sequences of spaces (#2 - `\s+`) are replaced with a single `_`.

```js
var s = 'This is new update. -(!@#$%)    1.0...'
document.write(s.replaceAll(/(\d\.\d)|\.|[^\s\w]/g, '$1').replace(/\s+/g,'_'));
```